# Ways to Recover Lost/Closed "Pinned" Tabs in Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, tabs, pinning

I know this was TECHNICALLY an already-answered issue awhile back - and then was subsequently brought to life again briefly - but I have been experiencing this issue (only twice, but I had about 15 pins; none of which I can bring up from my memory...hence the pins).

I noticed that a few people had posted regarding this question, or regarding a specific answer, but I have yet to find a working solution...at least not one which would assist me in my current situation [the situation being that I am unable to bring the pins BACK w/o knowing the URLs - which were plentiful and therefore definitely NOT remembered].

When I noticed that they were missing, it had been hours and an extremely large number of tabs had since been cycled through Chrome..) So, since my anticipated \ desired result is to somehow restore the pins, and I am unable to RESTORE CLOSED TABS in this instance, and the "CLICK RESTORE" comment wasn't even a valid comment (lol), I am at a fairly irritating and difficult crossroad...

I do not want to just say "screw it" because the items I had pinned were all pretty important items...hence the pins...yet I planned on cycling through them within the hour - and therefore made no effort to officially BOOKMARK them.

But my PC restarted in the middle of the night somehow, and the pins were lost.

Is it possible for me to somehow pull them back up, or any type of document, page, software, or anything else would be able to accomplish my desired result??
I have a feeling that it is not possible, due to the lack of answers on this page regarding what I would like to do, aside from REOPEN feature.
But it never hurts to ask - and maybe if someone else has this problem in the future, any type of answer is better than none, eh?

Thanks in advance to those who choose to (or TRY to) assist me! <3

Comment: I think I have covered the majority of any user-specific questions that may arrise, BUT if anyone has any questions - please feel free to ask, especially if you believe it will bring the issue anywhere closer to being resolved!  :)

Comment: Been researching this issue and it does seem that there isn't a solution easily recover the pinned tabs, only ideas for preventing the loss in the future.

Comment: I had the same issue recently and found - surprisingly - that Chrome seems to remember that these tabs were pinned. This was after I re-imaged my machine to upgrade to Sierra and lost my history but not my basic account info. When I simply opened a tab that had been previously pinned, it immediately jumped to the pinned location -- therefore I'm guessing that the pinned information was stored somewhere... I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Technically one possibility may bee to use the Bookmark Sync Function for that. Enable the Bookmark Sync and also enable Sync open Tabs. That way you should be able to open a Chrome on another PC/Mobile first so it opens all the open Tabs and resaves them on a proper close. Now when you turn on your Restarted PC it should also open all those Tabs again. Please test it before you rely on it. Since im away from home i actually couldn't test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the tabs or pages by finding them in the history folder. Also, you can bookmark really important pages so that you don't miss them if accidentally your tabs have been closed.